# ks package in R and plots

Tags: r

I am hoping someone might be able to help here. I've been using the `ks` package in R to develop multivariate kernel density estimates of my simulated 2- dimensional sample, $W = (W_1,W_2)$ and the components are iid. The code that is relevant is the following that I'm using:

```
init.bw = Hpi.diag(W,nstage='2',pilot='amse',pre='scale') #Initial plugin bandwidth
cv.bw = Hscv.diag(W,nstage=2,pre='scale',Hstart=init.bw) #Cross - validation bandwidth estimator
hat.fw.mult = kde(W,H=cv.bw,eval.points=W)
```

The problem is when I try to plot this estimator, I've followed the dcumentation and it appears it's something like:

```
plot(hat.fw.mult, display="slice", cont=c(25,50,75), abs.cont, 
     approx.cont=FALSE, xlab, ylab, zlab="Density function", add=FALSE, 
     drawpoints=FALSE, drawlabels=TRUE, theta=-30, phi=40, d=4,
     ptcol="blue", col="black")
```

The problem is I arrive at the following error:

```
Error in plotkde.2d(fhat, ...) : Need a grid of density estimates
```

and I have no idea how to fix this.. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might be better on a more R oriented site as this seems to be a programming rather than a statistical issue.